# How to refer to an attribute of a first object, which creates with a method a second object?

Tags: python-3.x

I'm currently trying to build a simple animation for a queuing model and I want to set the coords of any graphical object in dependence of its predecessor object. To do so, I call a method of the object (o1), which I want to animate. This method creates an object (o2) of another class, which represents the image. While creating o2, I want to pass an attribute of o1. This looks, for instance, like this:

```
class Queue(salabim.Queue):

    def setup(self, predecessor):
        self.predecessor = predecessor

    def animate(self, graphic):
        self.graphic = graphic

buffer_preprocessing = Queue(
    name = 'buffer_preprocessing',
    predecessor = source)

if env.animation is True:
    buffer_preprocessing.animate(graphic = Symbol_Queue(
        width = 80,
        height = ref_height,
        slots = 5,
        x = predecessor.graphic.x + predecessor.graphic.width + distance,
        y = y0,
        fillcolor = 'white'))
```

When compiling the program, I receive an error "[pylint] Undefined variable 'predecessor' [undefined-variable]".

Can somebody tell me, which keyword I need to use to refer to the attributes of the outside object "buffer_preprocessing"?

Thanks in advance :-)

Edit: It is possible to simplify my problem to the following code:

```
class OuterClass():

    def __init__(self, A):
        self.A = A

    def do_stuff(self, stuff):
        self.stuff = stuff

class InnerClass():

    def __init_(self, B):
        self.B = B

outerclass = OuterClass(A=1)
outerclass.do_stuff(stuff = InnerClass(B = 1 + A)) 
# Error: Undefined variable 'A' 
# How can I refer to the calling object 'outerclass' without giving the explicit name?
```

Comment: Its not at all obvious what you are trying to do here. Whether the `predecessor` argument you passed to `Queue` gets exposed as an attribute is entirely up to the implementation of the `Queue` class. It might be exposed or it might not (and we can't guess for you, since you haven't said where those classes come from). If you want the original value passed in as `predecessor`, you might still be able to access it as `source`, but maybe you want something different? There's no way for us to know.

Comment: In the example which object is o1 and which is o2?

Comment: @Blckknght : I've added the code of the Queue class to my question. I could pass the value by referring instead of 'predecessor' the object 'source'. However, thats not what I want.

Comment: @Tim : o1 is 'buffer_preprocessing' (and I call its animate-method). o2 is 'graphic', which I derrive from the class 'Symbol_Queue'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am guessing both the `Queue` and the `Symbol_Queue` since neither the `name` nor the `predecessor` parameters are part of python's `queue.Queue`.

If this is so, I believe the change needs to be implemented inside the code of the `Queue` class... maybe something along the lines:

First, expose the predecessor inside the `Queue`

```
class Queue(...):
    def __init__(self, name, predecessor, ...):
        ...
        # expose the predecessor
        self.predecessor = predecessor
```

or alternatively, if you need to do some processing/checking you can expose a property

```
class Queue(...):
    def __init__(self, name, predecessor, ...):
        ...
        # expose the predecessor
        self._predecessor = predecessor

    @property
    def predecessor(self):
        # .. some checks or processing
        return self._predecessor
```

Second, your code above will now become something like:

```
buffer_preprocessing = Queue(
    name = 'buffer_preprocessing',
    predecessor = source)

if env.animation is True:
    buffer_preprocessing.animate(graphic = Symbol_Queue(
        width = 80,
        height = ref_height,
        slots = 5,
        x = buffer_preprocessing.predecessor.graphic.x + buffer_preprocessing.predecessor.graphic.width + distance,
        y = y0,
        fillcolor = 'white'))
```

There probably might be better ways to pass this by changing a little the implementation of the `.animate`, but it's hard to say without looking at the implementation of the `Queue` and `Symbol_Queue` classes.

---

**EDIT 1:** *Using the simpler abstraction added to the question*

I believe the key here would be to include some kind of logic inside the `OuterClass.do_stuff`, since in there you can access the things within `self`. Of course, it depends how much you can "hardcode" into this function on the `OuterClass`.

Here is a suggestion (I define the Inner first for better readability):

```
class InnerClass():

    def __init_(self, B):
        self.B = B

class OuterClass():

    def __init__(self, A):
        self.A = A

    def do_stuff(self, stuff_to_create_inner):
        new_inner = InnerClass(B = 1 + self.A, **stuff_to_create_inner)
        # You can use "**" (dict unpacking), or pass them "by hand"

        # ...
        self.stuff = stuff

outerclass = OuterClass(A=1)
outerclass.do_stuff()  # in your example you may want to pass the width, height, ...
```

Finally, should you need to use/keep track of that inner object you created (I'm guessing you don't since you simply create on inside the method call), you could always have `OuterClass.do_stuff` return the created object.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your detailed answer. I've already considered the predecessor attribute within the definition of the class. I've added the definition of the Queue class in my start post. I hope, it's now more obvious what I'm trying to do. (Note: 'name' is an attribute, which a Queue object receives from its parent object (salabim.Queue)). Regarding the line in the third code box: "x =buffer_preprocessing.predecessor.graphic.x + buffer_preprocessing.predecessor.graphic.width + distance,"
Is it possible to refer to buffer_preprocessing in a more generic way? I don't want to use the object name.

Comment: I see, thanks for the response. I've edited my response above now following the simpler abstraction you created

Comment: Thank you! That solution fits to my requirements. All in all, it makes it easier, if I integrate the animation logic within the corresponding class, instead of separating both.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the simplification. Now it’s much clearer. In that case, you can simply pass the class as well as the argument to do_stuff rather than creating an object when calling the do_stuff function. For example,

```
class OuterClass():

    def __init__(self, A):
        self.A = A

    def do_stuff(self, my_class, other_input):
        self.obj = my_class(other_input+self.A)

class InnerClass():

    def __init_(self, B):
        self.B = B

outerclass = OuterClass(A=1)
outerclass.do_stuff(my_class = InnerClass, other_input=1)
```

Comment: Very interesting idea. However, I played a little bit around with your approach and (I think) it has one drawback, which make it unfeasible for me. The value of self.obj.B is always fix for every object I derrive from OuterClass. In my case, I need to define for every animation a specific x-coordinate, which I adjust with some fixed values. With the method above, I would define for every object the same x-coordinates and have no possibilities for individualizations.

Comment: You can add additional inputs. For example, make InnerClass with x+A and pass the value x into do_stuff. I’ve updated answer above. Or if you wanted something a bit more complicated, you can use more args or even kwargs.

Comment: You are right. I did not saw this. Very good solution approach. Thank you :-)

Comment: Addendum: If I could, I would also accept your answer, since it fit to my question. However, I decided for WillMonges approach, since it will avoid some redundancies in my main project.